# How to replace a SQL Server cursor with a different mechanism

Tags: json, sql-server

I am working on SQL Server 2008. I have to create json from two tables, which have a one-to-many relationship. The tables are `Customer` and `Orders`.

Each customer may have one or many orders. The json is constructed by first getting data from the customer table and then appending all the purchases they have made.

The following is my query. I have also enclosed the json output from the query. It works and creates valid jsons. The problem is that it's too slow as I am using a cursor to loop through the `Customer` table. I have managed to avoid cursor to get data from the `Orders` table by using for xml path. Since I have to handle millions of rows, I have to replace the cursor with some other mechanism.

```
DECLARE @PaymentType VARCHAR(50),
        @Email VARCHAR(100), 
        @OrderId INT

DECLARE CustomerCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT TOP 10 
        PaymentType, Email, OrderId 
    FROM 
        CUSTOMER

OPEN CustomerCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM CustomerCursor INTO @PaymentType, @Email, @OrderId

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @customer VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @order VARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @customer_with_order VARCHAR(MAX)

    -- construct order json
    SET @order =  '[' + STUFF((SELECT ',{"orderProductID":' + CAST(orderProductID AS VARCHAR) + 
                                      ',"productType":"' + ProductType + '"' + 
                                      ',"productName":"' + ProductName + '"' +
                                      ',"categoryName":"' + CategoryName + '"' + '}'
                               FROM ORDERS 
                               WHERE orderid = @OrderId
                               FOR XML PAT(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ']'
    -- construct customer json
    SET @customer = '{"email":"' + CASE WHEN @Email IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 
   @Email END + '"'
                + ',"eventName": "ChristmasSale", "dataFields": {' 
                + '"orderId":' + CAST(CASE WHEN @OrderId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
    @OrderId  END AS VARCHAR)                   
                + ',"paymentType":"' + CASE WHEN @PaymentType IS NULL THEN 
    '' ELSE @PaymentType END + '"'                  
                + ',"products": '

    -- combine these two
    SET @customer_with_order = @customer + @order + '}}'

    -- insert into CUSTOMER_ORDER_DATA
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ORDER_DATA(email, order_id, orders) 
    VALUES (@Email, @OrderId, @customer_with_order)

    FETCH NEXT FROM CustomerCursor INTO @PaymentType, @Email, @OrderId
END

CLOSE CustomerCursor
DEALLOCATE CustomerCursor
```

[image]

Comment: define slow here -- how fast do you expect it to take to generate 1 million json files?  Could just be your storage does not write fast enough.

Comment: I have to process 5 million records. The above query took 5 mins for 1000 jsons. At that rate, it will take 400 hours!

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to keep the values as relational data and create the JSON outside of SQL Server?

Comment: Hi Luis, I tried in C#, it also takes a similar amount of time as it also involves looping through the records.

Comment: I'm not saying to convert everything at once, Just convert to JSON as needed. You're also adding unnecessary data to your storage that will eventually hit you in a bad way. Each row you store is over 200 bytes of redundant data. All of this seems like bad design overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this, but I suspect you could rewrite the above as a set based method as below *(as I have no way of testing this, there is no way I can be certain this'll work, if it doesn't, you may need to troubleshoot it a little)*:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER_ORDER_DATA(email, order_id, orders)
SELECT C.Email,
       C.orderid,
       '{"email":"' + CASE WHEN @Email IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 
   @Email END + '"'
                + ',"eventName": "ChristmasSale", "dataFields": {' 
                + '"orderId":' + CAST(CASE WHEN @OrderId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
    @OrderId  END AS varchar)                   
                + ',"paymentType":"' + CASE WHEN @PaymentType IS NULL THEN 
    '' ELSE @PaymentType END + '"'                  
                + ',"products": ' +
    ('[' + STUFF((
    SELECT 
        ',{"orderProductID":' + CAST(orderProductID AS varchar)
        + ',"productType":"' + ProductType + '"'
        + ',"productName":"' + ProductName + '"'
        + ',"categoryName":"' + CategoryName + '"'          
        +'}'
    FROM ORDERS AS O
    WHERE O.orderid = C.orderid
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + ']')
FROM CUSTOMER AS C
```

Considering the OP has 5 millions rows, then this would likely be a bit much for one batch. Seperating it into batching of say 10,000 may be better for performance over all. Unfortunately the OP is still using 2008, so they don't have access to the `OFFSET` clause.

Comment: Hi Larnu, it worked perfectly with some minor modifications. This worked at least 600% faster than the one with a cursor. Thank you!